# Measuring the speed of light for different intensities

Tags: speed-of-light, specific-reference

Does someone know about some experiments which show that the speed of light is constant for different intensities? I need an ISI paper or a book. Maybe it is needed to name two papers that they measure the speed of light for different intensities. This will be useful as well. Thanks.

Comment: Well, the speed of light is a constant eh? While of course also taking refractive index into account.

Comment: @DakkVader I mean the speed of light for different intensities in the same environment.

Comment: Would the [tag:specific-reference] tag be appropriate?

Comment: @Chair Ok, thanks. I added that tag to the question.

Comment: I don't believe _both_ the [tag:resource-recommendations] and the [tag:specific-reference] tags are applicable. Depending on what you're looking for, you should pick one... Check out https://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/resource-recommendations/info and https://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/specific-reference/info I'm inclined to think that you want specific-reference, but you should look at those links and decide.

Comment: @Chair Yes, you are right. I edited my tags.

Comment: Does ISI index papers from before ISI was created? Because this research almost certainly predates 1960.

Comment: @ThePhoton I do not know when ISI index is created. However, a reliable paper or book is also good.

Answer (score 0):

The speed of light is constant in a material and the speed depends on the materials refractive index. The intensity should have no effect on the speed of the wave unless the material in which we exist depends on the incoming intensity. Then it is a parameter for the material and not a general photonic expression.

Comment: I do know that the intensity of light does not affect its speed. I just need a paper that confirms this issue. Test of the speed of light for different intensities.

Comment: Maybe it is needed to name two papers that they test the speed of light for different intensities. That will be useful as well.

Comment: Well, we here at physics stackexchange are not here to do your research for you in this way, you can look at google scholar and arxiv and all the other sources yourself. In any way, i'd reason that this would not be a hard experiment  to perform so might just as well do it yourself and include in your results? @Mehrab

Comment: I do not expect someone to do my research. I do mine by myself in my field of study gravity and cosmology. By the way, I do know how to search for something that I want. I used the tag 'specific-reference' for my question, and as you may know, it is used for questions seeking a single specific paper or requests for hard-to-find electronic copies. I think I asked my question in a right place and I do not need to do even easy experiments before asking my question here. You can just help if you have information about what I want. I do not expect you or someone else to search it for me.